# How to update parent window from child window with page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a page with a JavaScript where I need to set the value from a child window to a parent window but I don't want it to refresh the entire parent window and reload the page.

Currently I am using the following piece of code to change the URL of the parent:

```
 window.parent.opener.location.replace();
```

What would be the function for not refreshing the parent page?

Comment: What you want to do on parent window? In your code .location returns string and .replace() is a js method to replace part of string with something else.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try window.postMessage(), but there may be an easier way since this is a parent/child window.

Tutorial:
http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage

Some Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage